# Javascript function logs but doesnt do anything

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change some attributes when a button is pressed using Javascript. The thing is I can use `console.log` and it displays the data. Here's my function and HTML

```js
function change(e){
  console.log(e);
  e.disabled = true;
  e.innerText = 'Active';
  e.nextElementSibling.checked = true;
  if(e.getAttribute('id') == 'expanded-button'){
    let expanded = document.getElementById('expanded-button');
    expanded.innerText = 'Activate';
    expanded.disabled = false;
    expanded.nextElementSibling.checked = false;
  }else{
    let reversed = document.getElementById('reversed-button');
    reversed.innerText = 'Activate';
    reversed.disabled = false;
    reversed.nextElementSibling.checked = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="kiwi-reviews-template-options">
  <div class="kiwi-review-option">
    <div class="kiwi-review-option-header">
      <h2>Expanded</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="kiwi-option-footer">
      <button type="button" onclick="change(this)" id="expanded-button">Activate
    </button>
    <input type="radio" name="template" id="expanded-template" value="expanded"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="kiwi-review-option">
    <div class="kiwi-review-option-header">
      <h2>Reversed</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="kiwi-option-footer">
      <button type="button" onclick="change(this)" id="reversed-button">Activate
      </button>
      <input type="radio" name="template" id="reversed-template" value="reversed"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="kiwi-reviews-template-options">
  <div class="kiwi-review-option">
    <div class="kiwi-review-option-header">
      <h2>Expanded</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="kiwi-option-footer">
      <button type="button" onclick="change(this)" id="expanded-button">Activate
    </button>
    <input type="radio" name="template" id="expanded-template" value="expanded"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="kiwi-review-option">
    <div class="kiwi-review-option-header">
      <h2>Reversed</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="kiwi-option-footer">
      <button type="button" onclick="change(this)" id="reversed-button">Activate
      </button>
      <input type="radio" name="template" id="reversed-template" value="reversed"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>


function change(e){
  console.log(e);
  e.disabled = true;
  e.innerText = 'Active';
  e.nextElementSibling.checked = true;
  if(e.getAttribute('id') == 'expanded-button'){
    let expanded = document.getElementById('expanded-button');
    expanded.innerText = 'Activate';
    expanded.disabled = false;
    expanded.nextElementSibling.checked = false;
  }else{
    let reversed = document.getElementById('reversed-button');
    reversed.innerText = 'Activate';
    reversed.disabled = false;
    reversed.nextElementSibling.checked = false;
  }
}
</script>
```

When i use `console.log(e)` it displays `<button id="expanded-button" type="button" onclick="change(this)">` and its the correct button. But when i press the button it wont add the disabled attribute nor disable the other button for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're re-enabling the **same** button:

```
if(e.getAttribute('id') == 'expanded-button'){
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  let expanded = document.getElementById('expanded-button');
  // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You want to (re)enable the **other** button:

```
if(e.getAttribute('id') == 'expanded-button'){
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  let expanded = document.getElementById('reversed-button');
  // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(And the similar change in `else`.)

You can also simplify that code, since your `if` and `else` blocks are doing the same thing, just with different elements:

```js
function change(e){
  e.disabled = true;
  e.innerText = 'Active';
  e.nextElementSibling.checked = true;
  var otherId = e.id === 'expanded-button' ? 'reversed-button' : 'expanded-button';
  var other = document.getElementById(otherId);
  other.innerText = 'Activate';
  other.disabled = false;
  other.nextElementSibling.checked = false;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="change(this)" id="expanded-button" disabled>
    Active
</button>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<button type="button" onclick="change(this)" id="reversed-button">
    Activate
</button>
<input type="checkbox">
```